# Two alligned cylinders with opposite unopposing centripetal force outcome?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have a two meter wide cylinder with a diameter of 4 meters.  It is vertical to the ground and firmly anchored.  I spin it fast enough to hold my body to the outside walls. I am about 100 kilos but that really is not important.  I shut it down and get off.                                                                                                                    I now insert a second cylinder of a lessor diameter say 3.5 meters but same width inside this larger cylinder.  This second smaller cylinder is also free wheeling. It is anchored only to the first larger wheel. Looking at the cylinders from the side you can see only the larger cylinder but looking from the front or back you see a smaller cylinder inside a larger cylinder.  This can be done and it will be free wheeling.  I will not go into the mechanics of how that is done.  It is not important to the question.                                        I now rotate the larger wheel to the right once again fast enough to hold me to the side but not so fast as not to allow me movement.  Let's say fast enough to have an effect a little greater on me than gravity would if I was standing on the ground.  Now I rotate the inner wheel the opposite direction the same speed as the larger outside wheel compensating for the diameter difference.  I now am in the inner wheel.                                                               I already know I could stand up inside of the inner wheel and not appear to move from ground perspective as the two wheels are going the same speed but in opposite direction and both fast enough to hold me to the cylinder wall.  Where I start would not matter.  My question is would I be limited to my movement to the original standing location or could I walk around this inner wheel just like I would be walking through a park on a sunny day either direction?  I am thinking the latter.

Comment: Well, the floor on which you are walking, is it rotating w.r.t. an observer standing outside the entire wheel system?

Comment: @zero 6  I apparently have not been nearly enough clear. I am sorry for that.   This is so amazing that I am a bit surprised your comment is the only comment.  I am building this thing and have applied for a patent already. I will not give up how it is done ...yet.  Yes the floor on which I stand is rotating with respect to the  person standing on the absolute ground but I am not moving in relation to that person on the ground. unless I choose to walk.

Comment: @ zero 6  One more thing.  I in relationship to that person on the ground could be 180 degrees to that person and not feel the blood rush to my head but rather I would feel exactly as that person standing on the absolute ground

Comment: I must admit I already know the answer to original question too.  I was just hoping to blow a mind or two.

Comment: @ zero 6.  Yes the floor is rotating to that person on the ground but does not appear to be rotating to that person standing on the ground.  The floor on which I stand would look to that person just as I do standing there.  BUT. Looking at the works from the front with no guards the person on the ground can see the rotation in relation to that larger outside wheel.

Comment: I just need to get my writing working as well as my mind.  Hope you got it.

Comment: @ zero 6.  If this doesn't clear it up I am just can't write well enough.  If that person on the ground jumped into that inner floor where I was standing because it LOOKED  like it was not rotating he would get hurt or worse.

Comment: Since the floor on which you are standing (inner wheel) is rotating, you will experience centrifugal force on you in addition to that due to gravity, and if rotation is substantial enough for former to become comparable with the latter, I think it would be very uncomfortable for you. Not only has magnitude of effective $g$ changed for you, even its direction keeps changing.

Comment: @ Zero 21  Have small model done and big one for me half done.  Scales don't look like it will be that bad.  Ball bearing is a hoot.  Note:: the inner wheel does not have to over come or add to force of outer wheel.  The force of the outer wheel and inner wheel are not coming out to 1 plus 1 equals 2. My experience is fluid and mechanics.  I don't understand the math to this but don't need to.

Comment: @ Zero 21  The direction of G does not keep changing.

Comment: @Zero. sorry about the 21.  Too many things at once.

Comment: @Zero  As no on sees the potential for this but you were a bit curious, one last thing on the matter from me.  This will make a tremendous ride at any amusement park.  I think I will live long enough for that.  Now charge these wheels magnetically with opposites with mega voltage. Be a bit curious on that.  I may not make it to that finish line.  I weigh about 220 and safely will weigh less than 500 in the wheels.  In a chair anyone who rides a roller coaster could go in my wheel.  Jump in it from the outside and you will stick like glue.

Comment: Best of luck. Always make sure you get the physics right. Don't hesitate to speak to people who know more about things that you don't have an expertise in.